# How to bring target document to the front and fix my photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop

So I'm building out a script to pull numerically numbered images from a folder and import and place them in specific coordinates on a Photoshop document. When running I go through the motion of picking the folder and inputting the order in which the images will be laid out but then Photoshop gives me this error:

```
Error 8100: The requested action requires that the target document is 
the frontmost document.

in reference to this line Line: 50
->    placedLayer.translate(placement.x, placement.y);
```

I've tried a couple different ways to get the doc to be the frontmost such as:

```
app.activeDocument = doc

bringToFront()

moveToEnd()

doc.setActive();
```

none of which seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable as the first (source) document that you open:

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
```

You can then constantly switch back to it after another document has been opened with:

```
app.activeDocument = srcDoc;
```

Comment: thank you, was able to get it working lol, still new to javascript and photoshops documentation was kicking my ass